# Delphi - How to genericize query result set

Tags: delphi, dataset

I am working with multiple databases within the same application.  I am using drivers from two different companies.  Both companies have tTable and tQuery Descendants that work well.

I need a way to have generic access to the data, regardless of which driver/tQuery component I am using to return a set of data. This data would NOT tie to components, just to my logic.

For example...(pseudocode) Let's create a function which can run against either tQuery component

```
function ListAllTables(NameOfDatabase : String) :ReturnSet??
begin

If NameOfDataBase = 'X' then use tQuery(Vendor 1)
    else use tQuery(Vendor 2)
RunQuery;
Return Answer...
end;
```

When NORMALLY running a query, I do

```
Query.Open;
While not Query.EOF do
   begin
   Read my rows..
   next;
end;
```

If I am CALLING ListAllTables, what is my return type so that I can iterate through the rows?  Each tQuery Vendor is different, so I can't use that (can I, and if so, would I want to?)  I could build a Memory Table, and pass that back, but that seems like extra work for ListAllRows to build a memory table, and then to pass it back to the calling routine so that it can "un-build", i.e. iterate through the rows...

What are your ideas and suggestions?
Thanks
GS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all Delphi datasets descend from TDataset, and most useful behavior is defined on TDataset.

Therefore, if you assign each table or query to a variable of type TDataset, you should be able to perform your logic on that dataset in a vendor neutral fashion.

I would also isolate the production of the datasets into a set of factory functions that only create the vendor-specific dataset and return it as a TDataset.  Each factory function goes in it's own unit.  Then, only those small units need have any knowledge of the vendor specific components.

Comment: You cannot use the TDataSet class for this, but you can use the TClientDataSet if you wish.

Comment: @Misha: Why not? Larry is talking about `var MyDataSet: TDataSet` and `MyDataSet := TSomeSpecificDescendantDataSet.Create` or just `MyDataSet := SomeSpecificDescendentDataSetReference`. And then only using the common functionality provided by TDataSet. Perfectly feasible.

Comment: @Misha: Actually, the ability to have polymorphic descendants of a single base case but to treat the descendants as if they *were* the base class to access the common, base functionality is one of the primary reasons to use object-oriented programming to begin with.  TDataset, in my opinion, is one of the all-time most successful uses of object-oriented design.

Comment: +1, Larry. @Misha, you certainly can. That's exactly what it was originally designed to do, all the way back to Delphi 1.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking not of running through the result set but more of generic data access itself (too many other things on my mind to read the question properly), e.g. none of the query access components have a base "query-like" abstract class

Comment: Casting both vendors TQuery components as TDataSet and using that as a Return value worked.  That is the easiest, and appears to be the most flexible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use IProviderSupport to generalize the query execution. I am expecting, that used query's are supporting IProviderSupport. This interface allows to set command text, parameters, execute commands, etc.
2. The common denominator for used query's is TDataSet. So, you will need pass TDataSet reference.

For example:

```
var
  oDS: TDataSet;
...
if NameOfDataBase = 'X' then
  oDS := T1Query.Create(nil)
else
  oDS := T2Query.Create(nil);
(oDS as IProviderSupport).PSSetCommandText('select * from mytab');
oDS.Open;
while not oDS.Eof do begin
  //
  oDS.Next;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could consider a universal data access component such as UniDAC or AnyDAC.  This allows you to use only one component set to access different databases in a consistent way.

You might also be interested in DataAbstract from RemObjects.  A powerful data abstraction, multi-tier, remoting solution with a lot of features.  Not inexpensive, but excellent value for the money.

Relevant links:

- http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/
- http://www.devart.com/unidac/
- http://www.remobjects.com/da/

Comment: I actually am using AnyDAC for SQL support, as well as ComponentAce's ABS Database.

Comment: Ok, I see.  Although I did not provide a coding solution, I'm not sure that my suggestion to consider components that specifically deal with the concept of working with multiple databases deserved someone's downvote. :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to have ListAllTables return (or populate) a stringlist.